# How would I show the relations on this set of S?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I want to show that the set below is reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive.

**Let $S$ be the set of positive integer divisors of $180$ and consider the relation $\mid$ on $S$.**

I understand that $a$ reflexive is for all $(a,a)$ within $S$. Anti-symmetric is for all $(a,b)\in S$, $(b,a)$ doesn't exist, and transitive is for all $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ there is $(a,c)$.

How would I be able to show each of these? Would I show how they can or can't be divided within the set and that is must hold for **ALL** elements within the set S?

Comment: Yes, you would need to do so. Work with the definition of $\mid$, that is $a\mid b\Leftrightarrow \exists k\in\mathbb Z:b=ak$. And don't let the $180$ fool you, as this holds for all positive numbers.

Comment: And a correction, anti-symmetric requires $a \ne b$, or else you run into trouble with reflexivity.